# Using Jenkins to start a cmd(Win 10) script that does a pull on a remote repo in the local network fails. The same commands by hand work

Tags: windows, git, jenkins

Soo, I am try to periodically run a pull request using a jenkins server. I set the Jenkins Job to execute the same steps I do by hand.

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer unknown or anonymous 
Baue auf dem Agenten „int-test-a-3“ (windows) in Arbeitsbereich C:\Jenkins\workspace\int-test- 
a-3\int-test-a-3-git-sync [int-test-a-3-git-sync] $ cmd /c call 
C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins7612063198399964523.bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\int-test-a-3\int-test-a-3-git-sync>cd                             C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool 


C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool>git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool>git remote -v 
origin  \\INT-TEST-A-0\SST_Repository_Origin (fetch)
origin  \\INT-TEST-A-0\SST_Repository_Origin (push)

C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool>git fetch 
fatal: '\\INT-TEST-A-0\SST_Repository_Origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool>git pull 
fatal: '\\INT-TEST-A-0\SST_Repository_Origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\Users\Secret\AppData\Roaming\SerialScriptingTool>exit 1 
Build step 'Windows Batch-Datei ausführen' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The weird part is, if I am on the same machine and running the same commands by hand they work and the fetch and pull commands work correctly. When I check with a whoami command which user Jenkins runs the cmd as it is also the same and only user of the PC. I mean the remotes are still the same in the config and the repo exists and is reachable over the network.

Comment: Have you tried to execute those commands in a non interactive `cmd /c call script.bat` execution ? I'm not familiar with Windows or cmd.exe, but I know that in other setups (namely : bash on linux), running a script in a non interactive shell does not load the same files at startup (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, ...)

Comment: Also : check the complete environment (`cmd.exe` must have the equivalent of the `env` command ?), not just the active user

Comment: The details depend on many things, including the OS, and I don't "do" WIndows, but: Jenkins deliberately sets up a "sandboxed" workspace that has no access to things it shouldn't have access to. This may prevent you from reaching out to `origin`. If that's the case, you must either provide everything inside the sandbox, or instruct Jenkins to allow the sandbox additional outside access (in a Jenkins and OS dependent way).